# SwiftUI List is not showing any items

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationlink

I want to use NavigationView together with the ScrollView, but I am not seeing List items.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView{
                VStack {
                    Text("Some stuff 1")
                    List{
                        Text("one").padding()
                        Text("two").padding()
                        Text("three").padding()
                    }
                    Text("Some stuff 2")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

All I see is the text. If I remove ScrollView I see it all, but the text is being pushed to the very bottom. I simply want to be able to add List and Views in a nice scrollable page.

Comment: Why don't use VStack instead of List, it is already in ScrollView?

Comment: I want to be able to use List dynamically, List(array) { item in ...

Comment: I would guess wrapping a List inside a Scrollview is not such a good idea since there might be conflicts between the scroll handlers

Answer (score 59):

The `ScrollView` expects dimension from content, but `List` expects dimension from container - as you see there is conflict, so size for list is undefined, and a result rendering engine just drop it to avoid disambiguty.

The solution is to define some size to List, depending of your needs, so ScrollView would now how to lay out it, so scroll view could scroll entire content and list could scroll internal content.

Eg.

[image: demo]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.defaultMinListRowHeight) var minRowHeight

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView{
                VStack {
                    Text("Some stuff 1")
                    List {
                        Text("one").padding()
                        Text("two").padding()
                        Text("three").padding()
                    }.frame(minHeight: minRowHeight * 3).border(Color.red)
                    Text("Some stuff 2")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! It is working but I have dynamic height so can't fix minHeight. If I'll fix it will show an extra scroll or my content will be truncated. Any suggestions?

Comment: How very silly that they don't have a minimum size or something to let devs know that the List is in fact there, thanks for the info!

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to throw out an answer that fixed what I was seeing very similar to the original problem - I had put a `Label()` item ahead of my `List{ ... }` section, and when I deleted that `Label() { }` I was able to see my `List` content again.  Possibly List is buggy with other items surrounding it (Xcode 13 Beta 5).

Comment: I agree. I tried to put a List inside a ScrollView a couple of times but it never worked as expected. If you go with ScrollView implement your own list item.