# SwiftUI Picker in Form - Can't Dynamically Size the Form Space

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, picker

I'm struggling with a view where I want to have multiple pickers embedded in
other views. When I wrap the pickers in a Form, I get the desired behavior for the
picker but there is a lot of extra space around the pickers that I can't seem to
automatically adjust.

This is an example - the space in the red outline seems to be determined by the other
view elements not the size of the picker.

[image]

I can, of course, hard-code a frame height for the Form but that is trial and error
and would only be specific to the device and orientation. I have tried multiple
versions of Stacks inside Stacks with padding, GeometryReader etc, but I have not come up with any
solution. As an aside, I DO want the picker labels, otherwise I could just remove
the Form.

I also tried setting UITableView.appearance().tableFooterView in an init() but that did not work either.

Here is a simplified version:

```
struct ContentView4: View {
    @State var selectedNumber1: Int = 1
    @State var selectedNumber2: Int = 2
    @State var selectedNumber3: Int = 3

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Text("Compare up to 3")
                        .font(.caption)
                    Spacer()
                }//h
            
                Form {//for pickers
                        Picker(selection: $selectedNumber1, label: Text("A")) {
                            ForEach(0..<10) {
                                Text("\($0)")
                            }
                        }//picker

                        Picker(selection: $selectedNumber2, label: Text("B")) {
                            ForEach(0..<10) {
                                Text("\($0)")
                            }
                        }//picker

                        Picker(selection: $selectedNumber3, label: Text("C")) {
                            ForEach(0..<10) {
                                Text("\($0)")
                            }
                        }//picker
                }//form for pickers
                .padding(.horizontal, 10)
                //.frame(height: 200) //don't want to hard code this
            
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    HStack {
                        Text("A")
                            .frame(width: 100)
                        Text("B")
                            .frame(width: 100)
                        Text("C")
                            .frame(width: 100)
                    }
                    .padding(.horizontal, 10)
                
                    ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                        VStack(alignment: .leading){
                            Text("A title line")
                                .font(.headline)
                                .padding(.vertical, 5)
                            HStack {
                                Text("Number")
                                    .frame(width: 100)
                                Text("Number")
                                    .frame(width: 100)
                                Text("Number")
                                    .frame(width: 100)
                            }
                            Text("Another title line")
                                .font(.headline)
                                .padding(.vertical, 5)
                            HStack {
                                Text("Something")
                                    .frame(width: 100)
                                Text("Something")
                                    .frame(width: 100)
                                Text("Something")
                                    .frame(width: 100)
                            }
                            Text("A Third title line")
                                .font(.headline)
                                .padding(.vertical, 5)
                            HStack {
                                Text("More")
                                    .frame(width: 100)
                                Text("More")
                                    .frame(width: 100)
                                Text("More")
                                    .frame(width: 100)
                            }
                        }
                    }//scroll
                    .padding(.horizontal, 10)
                }
                .navigationBarTitle("Compare Three", displayMode: .inline)
            }
        }//nav
    }//body
}//struct
```

Interestingly, I am able to get a solution by removing the form and wrapping each
picker in a menu, like this:

```
Menu {
    Picker(selection: $selectedNumber2, label: EmptyView()) {
        ForEach(0..<10) {
            Text("\($0)")
        }
    }//picker
} label: {
    HStack {
    Text("B")
        Spacer()
        Image(systemName: "chevron.right")
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: 14, height: 14)
    }//h
}//menu label
```

However, I still like the look of the Form better if I could automatically configure
the space around the Form items.

Any guidance would be appreciated. Xcode 13.4, iOS 15.5

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/61438156/12299030?

Comment: Interesting - that confirms that there is an issue, but I don't want to hard code the height. I see there is an answer below based on creating a view from @ViewBuider - I'll give that a try. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Form` (and `List`) is not meant to be stacked inside other views like this, which is why it has such strange behavior.

Thankfully, it's fairly simple to recreate the stuff you do want using `NavigationLink`. Here’s a quick example of a couple custom views that do just that:

```
// drop-in NavigationLink replacement for Picker
struct NavigationButton<Content: View, SelectionValue: Hashable> : View {
    @Binding var selection: SelectionValue
    @ViewBuilder let content: () -> Content
    @ViewBuilder let label: () -> Text
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink {
            PickerView(selection: $selection, content: content, label: label)
        } label: {
            HStack {
                label()
                Spacer()
                Text(String(describing: selection))
                    .foregroundColor(.secondary)
            }
            .contentShape(Rectangle())
        }
        .buttonStyle(NavigationLinkButtonStyle())
    }
}

// subview for the Picker page, which lets us use `dismiss()` 
// to pop the subview when the user selects an option
struct PickerView<Content: View, SelectionValue: Hashable> : View {
    @Binding var selection: SelectionValue
    @ViewBuilder let content: () -> Content
    @ViewBuilder let label: () -> Text
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Picker(selection: $selection, content: content, label: label)
                .pickerStyle(.inline)
                .labelsHidden()
                .onChange(of: selection) { _ in
                    dismiss()
                }
        }
        .navigationTitle(label())
    }
}

// recreate the appearance of a List row
struct NavigationLinkButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        HStack {
            configuration.label
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            Image(systemName: "chevron.right")
                .font(.footnote.bold())
                .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.tertiaryLabel))
        }
        .padding()
        .background(
            Rectangle()
                .fill(configuration.isPressed ? Color(UIColor.quaternaryLabel) : Color(UIColor.systemBackground))
        )
    }
}
```

If you like the `.insetGrouped` style you got using `Form`, we can replicate that by putting `NavigationButton` inside a clipped `VStack`:

```
VStack(spacing: 0) {

    NavigationButton(selection: $selectedNumber1) {
        ForEach(0..<10) {
            Text("\($0)")
        }
    } label: {
        Text("A")
    }
    
    Divider()
    
    NavigationButton(selection: $selectedNumber2) {
        ForEach(0..<10) {
            Text("\($0)")
        }
    } label: {
        Text("B")
    }
}
.clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 11))
.padding()
.background(Color(UIColor.systemGroupedBackground))
```

And here’s a screenshot showing my custom views above your original `Form`.

[image]

(And if you like Picker as a popup menu, you could use Menu instead of NavigationLink)

Comment: Fantastic. This works just as I wanted. I have not used @ViewBuilder much and was just starting to study it yesterday. Great solution. Thanks, Adam.