# SwiftUI ZStack first element is not displayed

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, zstack

I'm new to SwiftUI, and I have a simple app with a ZStack:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var num : Int = 1
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            ZStack{
                Text("asd")
                    .foregroundColor(.blue)
                    .frame(width: 400, height: 400, alignment: .center)
                    .background(.blue)
                VStack{
                    List{
                        ListItem()
                        ListItem()
                    }
                }
                .toolbar{
                    Button{
                        num+=1
                    } label: {
                        Label("Add", systemImage: "plus")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the blue frame with the text is not displayed:
[image]

Why is this happening?

Comment: It is in ZStack, so under List, where did you expect to see it?

Comment: So how do I make the list smaller so I can see the frame..?

Comment: Not really sure what do you mean... why do you need List then? List consumes all screen until you give it explicit frame. And List is not transparent, so what's the sense to have text under opaque List in full screen?

Comment: So how can I give the list the height to wrap it's items only instead of the whole screen?

Comment: Probably you need something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/61438156/12299030. Your explanation and goal are not clear.

Comment: agreed with Asperi. please provide us a sample picture of what you want to achieve. I did not understand what you meant by "text and the frame to be behind the list". If it is behind the list, how do you expect to see it? Because List will overlay on it.

Answer (score 1):

It is because the `Text View` is underneath the `List` in the `ZStack`.

If you move the Text to after the list, it will be shown on top.

```swift
ZStack {
    VStack{
        List {
            ListItem()
            ListItem()
        }
        .listStyle(.insetGrouped)
    }
    .toolbar{
        Button{
            num+=1
        } label: {
            Label("Add", systemImage: "plus")
        }
    }
    
    Text("asd")
        .foregroundColor(.blue)
        .frame(width: 400, height: 400, alignment: .center)
        .background(.blue)
}
```

Comment: But I want the text and the frame to be under the list

Comment: You would have to make the background of the list transparent. I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: You can use [SwiftUI-Introspect](https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect) to make the background of the list transparent: `.introspectTableView { tableView in tableView.backgroundColor = .clear }`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using ZStack to wrap up everything.

Solution: Change from ZStack to VStack.

```
NavigationView{
        VStack{ //this part
```

Comment: But I don't want a VStack, I want the text and the frame to be behind the list.