# ForEach inside a List not showing results

Tags: swiftui, core-data

I've got a view that draws its content from core data using a `FetchRequest` and stores the results in the var `navigations`. I want to display the content of `navigations` inside a `List` using a `ForEach`. I've done this on other views many times, but for some reason it doesn't seem to work here. If I place the exact same code inside a `VStack` it works fine. Clearly I must be doing something wrong on a very basic level, but I've wracked my brains and cannot figure out where I've gone wrong.

I'm sure there's something embarrassing simple that I've overlooked here. Please help me find it.

In the code below, `event` is passed in by the view that calls this for the purpose of filtering just this event's data

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext

    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [SortDescriptor(\.date)],
        predicate: NSPredicate(value: false),
        animation: .default)
    private var navigations:FetchedResults<NavEntry>
    
    var event: Event
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ScrollView{
            let _ = updatePredicate()
            
            VStack {
                Text("ForEach inside a VStack:")
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    ForEach(navigations) {nav in
                        Text("\(longTime(date: nav.date)) \(nav.note)")
                    }
                }
                Text("\n ForEach inside a List:")
                List {
                    ForEach(navigations) {nav in
                        Text("\(longTime(date: nav.date)) \(nav.note)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func updatePredicate() {
        navigations.nsPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "event == %@", event)
    }
}
```

Here's a screenshot of the output:

[image]

Comment: does this answer your question: [SwiftUI List inside ScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60688913/swiftui-list-inside-scrollview)

Comment: Yes, this got me to a working List view. Oddly, I've done ForEach iterations inside a List many times before without having problems, but apparently I always had an outer container with a defined size.